# perl: warning: Setting locale failed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, perl, locale

Parece existir um erro com as definições locais do [Perl](https://www.perl.org/) e/ou do sistema, mas os detalhes obtidos não clarificam bem o que se está a passar:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_PAPER = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
    LC_TIME = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

Este erro é visível, por exemplo, ao fazer uso do comando [`adduser`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/adduser.8.html):

```
# sudo adduser zuul
```

## Pergunta

Como avaliar e resolver qualquer que seja este problema com as definições locais ?

<sup>x86_64

Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS

Perl 5, version 14, subversion 2 (v5.14.2)</sup>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [comando `locale-gen`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man8/locale-gen.8.html) para recompilar os arquivos de definição de *localidade*:

```all
~$ sudo locale-gen pt_PT.UTF-8
[sudo] password for [usuário]: 
Generating locales...
  pt_PT.UTF-8... up-to-date
Generation complete.
~$
```

Feito isto, será necessário reconfigurar a *localidade* usando o [comando `dpkg-reconfigure`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/pt/man8/dpkg-reconfigure.8.html):

```all
~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
[sudo] password for [usuário]: 
Generating locales...
  en_AG.UTF-8... done
  en_AU.UTF-8... done
  ...
  pt_BR.UTF-8... done
  pt_PT.UTF-8... up-to-date
Generation complete.
~$
```

---

Se você quiser fazer isto de [maneira manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale#Changing_settings_permanently), modique o arquivo *`etc/default/locale`*, ou para um usuário específico, o arquivo *.pam_environment* localizado na pasta `HOME` do usuário.

```all
~$ nano /etc/default/locale    # todo sistema
~$ nano $HOME/.pam_environment # usuário em específico
```

Em versões mais antigas é possível usar o [comando `update-locale`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/update-locale.8.html):

```all
~$ sudo update-locale LANG=pt_PT.UTF-8 LC_ALL=pt_PT.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente esta faltando os pacotes de linguagem da glibc. Apesar das variáveis estarem definidas, se não exisitirem os binários não adianta.

Verifique se os pacotes de linguagem estão disponíveis. No Fedora são os seguintes:

- langpacks-pt
- glibc-langpack-pt

Depois de instalados, excute:

```
$locale
```

`LANG=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=`

Se a sua saída estiver similar a esta ok. Se não, execute:

`$localectl set-locale LANG=pt_BR.utf8`

Isto deve resolver seus problemas.

Answer (score -1):

Eu estava tendo esse problema no meu servidor quando quando logava via ssh. O que resolveu pra mim foi o seguinte: fiz login no meu servidor, dentro dele eu abri o arquivo `/etc/environment` como root e adicionei essas linhas:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```